# AWK, 2 prints with different separators from the same file

Tags: awk

Lets say I have this line

```
"58062","2022-03-23 10:07:21.718670","Standard query 0x04c0 AAAA contoso.local"
```

And I just want to print "contoso.local" which is the 5th column from the last block inside double quotes.

I get what I want by doing this:

```
cat file.log | awk -F "," '{print $3}' | awk '{print $5}'
```

Is there a more elegant way of achiving this? I've tried an awk inside the first awk but that does not work, I believe I am using GNU Awk that comes in Ubuntu 18.

EDIT:

This indeed is a log file (lots of filtered dns queries) where all lines have the same structure, to be more specific: I don't strictly need the last word from the line, I could for example need to extract the alphanumeric code right before the domain, it would always be the 3th column of the last block.

```
"58062","2022-03-23 10:07:21","Standard query 0x04c0 A contoso.local"
"58063","2022-03-23 10:08:22","Standard query 0xcif0 A something.local"
"58064","2022-03-23 10:09:23","Standard query 0xEec0 AAAA domain.local"
```

For the file above this works:

```
cat file.log | awk -F "," '{print $3}' | awk '{print $4}'
```

Comment: Try: `gawk -F"," '{ FS=" "; $0=$3; print $5 }' file.log`   Only the double quote need some more attention...

Comment: "I believe I am using GNU Awk that comes in Ubuntu 18"  Do not believe, just check, and do `awk --version`

Comment: There's also the awk `split()` function: `awk -F"," '{split($3,a," "); print a[5]}' file.log` You could add double quotes to your split delimiter too and just grab the 6th element: `awk -F"," '{split($3,a,"[  \"]"); print a[6]}'` (I think that's the right syntax).

Comment: assuming the file may have additional lines it would be helpful if we had more sample data; do we need to extract a string from all lines or just some lines? could there be fewer/more then 3x comma delimited fields and if so are we only looking at the 3rd comma delimlited field or the last field? could the 3rd field have fewer/more than 5x space delimited fields and if so are we only looking at the 5th or last space delimited field?

Comment: @Luuk your answer almost works, I loose the first record. I don't understand the $0=$3

Comment: Added my answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some clarification on my comment:

```
gawk -F"," '{ FS=" "; $0=$3; print $5 }' file.log
```

This will work when `file.log` only has one line, and not when it contains multiple lines. This can be fixed by doing:

```
gawk -F"," '{ FS=" "; $0=$3; print $5; FS="," }' file.log
```

In steps:

1. `-F","`  The field separator is set to a comma
2. `FS=" "`  The field separator is set to a space. This is done after the first line has been read.
3. `$0=$3`  Re-assinging `$0` with a value (in this case `$3`) will make gawk split that value again, by the `FS`.
4. `print $5` print the 5th field.
5. `FS=","`  Set the field separator back to a "," to process the next line.

Because of this assigning values to FS multiple times, it is probably better to use `split()`

This will lead to:

```
gawk -F"," '{ split($3,a," "); print a[5] }' file.log
```

(As also given by JNevil in the comments)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is simply to use `sed` with the usual substitution for (`'s/find/replace/' file`) capturing the last whitespace separated text in the line up to the first `'"'` and reinserting that text using the first named backreference.

```sh
sed -E 's/^.*[[:space:]]([^"]+)"$/\1/'
```

The `-E` option above specifies *Extended Regular Expression* syntax. If your `sed` doesn't support `-E` (or `-r`), you simply have to state the match a 2nd time with `*` (zero or more occurrences) and escape the parenthesis in the capture-group. With Basic Regular Expression that would be:

```sh
sed -E 's/^.*[[:space:]]\([^"][^"]*\)"$/\1/'
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your example line in `file`, you would get:

```
$ sed -E 's/^.*[[:space:]]([^"]+)"$/\1/' file
contoso.local
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your data. If the question is: 'Print the last "word" without ending quote', then maybe:

```
sed -E 's/.* (.*)"/\1/'
awk -F'.* |"' '{$0=$2}1'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# grep -oP '([^\s]+)(?="$)' file.log 
contoso.local
something.local
domain.local
```

1.grep has lookaround support，you need add -P option to your grep (if your grep supports it). since PCRE supports them.

2.\s matches any whitespace, ^ Indicates negation, + Indicates matching one or more times，"$ means ending with a quotation mark

Answer (score 0):

Answer from @JNevill in the comments above

```
awk -F"," '{split($3,a,"[  \"]"); print a[5]}' test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're VERY certain whatever you need is after the last space/tab of `$3`, then something like

```
      # using FS to deal with trailing double-quote
 
      mawk 'sub("^.+ ",_,$(($!_=$_=$3)<_))' FS=',|["]$'
or
      # using gsub() to deal with trailing double-quote
 
      mawk 'gsub("^.+ |["]$",_,$(NF=($_=$3)~_))' FS=','
or
      #using RS to deal with trailing double-quote
 
      mawk 'sub("^.+ ",_,$(NF=($_=$3)~_))' FS=',' RS='"?\n' 


"58062","2022-03-23 10:07:21","Standard query 0x04c0 A contoso.local"
"58063","2022-03-23 10:08:22","Standard query 0xcif0 A something.local"
"58064","2022-03-23 10:09:23","Standard query 0xEec0 AAAA domain.local"

contoso.local
something.local
domain.local
```

or perhaps

```
 echo "${aaa}" \
 \
 | mawk 'BEGIN { FS=_="," 
   
   } $!+_=$+(FS=_)=substr("",$(($!+_=$3)<"")=$+(FS=" |[\42]$")) $--NF'  

contoso.local
something.local
domain.local
```